# ObjectId is replaced with String so I cannot retrieve document

Tags: angular, mongodb, nestjs, typegoose

I can create a survey with this body:

```
{
  "name":"name of survey",
  "description":"description of survet",
  "openAt":"2020-02-12T23:00:00.000Z",
  "closeAt":"2020-02-18T23:00:00.000Z",
  "questions":[..],
}
```

The server retrieve the user from jwt and store it as:

[image: Screenshot of MongoAtlas document]

*screenshot of Survey document in MongoAtlas (only user part)*

Now, if I edit my survey with this body:

```
{
  "createdAt":"2020-02-02T16:12:14.082Z",
  "_id":"5e36f4e008caf531ce848954",
  "name":"new name",
  ...
  "user":{
    "createdAt":"2020-02-02T16:12:14.063Z",
    "rank":0,"_id":"5e2f534422b6047e23c7f839",
    "_id":"5e2f534422b6047e23c7f839",
    ...
  }
}
```

My document is edited and _id type is become String type instead ObjectId

[image]

*screenshot of Survey document in MongoAtlas (only user part)*

Now this code doesn't work anymore because of the string type (when _id is ObjectId it does work)

```
await this.surveyModel.where('user._id').equals(user._id)
```

**I'm using Angular 8 for frontend and Nest.js + TypeGoose for backend.**

I don't know exactly how to fix this, may should I create a middleware that replace String _id to ObjectId ? Or should I use ObjectId in my frontend instead string ? Or should I use string by default with TypeGoose instead ObjectId ? Theses are the 3 solutions I imagine would do the works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve your data with the `id`. For example,

```
await this.surveyModel.where('user.id').equals(user.id)
```

Updated:

```
var id = parseInt(ObjectId.valueOf(), 16);
```

Reference: [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/#ObjectId.valueOf)

Also check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543790/mongoose-objectid-to-number/18545319) helps.

Comment: My model (neither survey or user) has not id property
So if I do equals(user.id) I got "property id doesn't exist on type User)
Should I create it ? Ur link doesn't help

Comment: No you shouldn't create one. It was to access the virtual id. Did you try using `ObjectId.valueOf()`? If not, kindly have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Where want U I use ValueOf objectId ? It's not vanilla mongo, it's TypeGoose so I cannot really follow the mongoose documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the default "_id" from mongoose it should be "ObjectId", and if it stores it as an string maybe try to set the id manually `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("Some24HexString")`

Maybe you could update your question to include on how you save it to the db & your model used